# Tricking the jsfiddle-Link-Only-Filter with parentheses

Tags: bug, quality-filter, jsfiddle

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414985/hide-method-of-jquery-not-woking-after-clicking-a-button) asked a rather vague question with just a link to jsfiddle - but crucially the link was placed inside parenthesis

> Sample code here (http://jsfiddle.net/CPtp4/4/)

I tried to edit this question to remove the parenthesis making the link clickable, but when I went to save I got the message about "making the question relevant by including the relevant code - not just linking to jsfiddle"

So it seems a user can bypass this warning by just wrapping the link in parentheses.

Comment: That should thus be closed as NARC or too localized.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Totally, but this meta post wasn't about the content of that particular question, it was about the ability to bypass a warning in a very simple way!

Comment: of course, that's why I made my remark a comment, not an answer. :-)

Comment: FYI, I have updated the question to contain the JSFiddle code. The revision referred to is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13414985/1